# Store multiple rows in session array on form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 4 input fields in my form.

a) name
b) addr
c) cost
d) combo

I want to get the values of the fields (when submitted) and put them in session. I want to store multiple rows in the session so I'm using an array. The following is the code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {   
    $_SESSION['arr'] = array();
    $_SESSION['arr'][] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['arr'][] = $_POST['addr'];
    $_SESSION['arr'][] = $_POST['cost'];
    $_SESSION['arr'][] = $_POST['combo'];
}
```

I'm iterating in the following way:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong?

I would also like to point out that I would later want to insert the rows of my session array into MySQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I need you to clarify one thing. Are you trying to get the POST data in key-value pair within the session? Something like this :-

```
Array
 (
   [arr] => Array
    (
        [name] => XYZ
        [addr] => ABC
        [cost] => 100
        [combo] => ABCD
    )

 )
```

If so, you could try this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {   

    $_SESSION['arr'][] = array(
        "name" => $_POST['name'],
        "addr" => $_POST['addr'],
        "cost" => $_POST['cost'],
        "combo" => $_POST['combo']
    );
}
```

If you let me know what exactly you're trying to print here, that too in which format, that'd make things easier.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not using key:value pair. But I'll give that a try. Thanks once again!!

Comment: I'm just trying to get my form data and store them in session array. User will keep adding multiple items. So I want to keep all the items in session and finally when user is done adding, I'll insert the data in my database. That's the whole idea. By the way, I've tried the way you have described above but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Oh, okay. That's because the way I have written, it's creating a new array every time. Please take a look at my new answer. I've changed $_SESSION['arr'] to $_SESSION['arr'][]. That will work just fine! :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! That worked! You rock. I would like to take this opportunity to ask another help. Could you please give me an idea how I can take this array and insert each row into mysql table. Each row will have an unique id in the table of course (primary key). Thank you very much!! :)